# oracle foreign key returns null

Tags: oracle, triggers, constraints

currently i am facing an oracle constraints issue.

After submiting an insert my foreign key constraint(s) won't fire. What it should do is giving two tables the same ID, but unfortunately only the one table with the primary Key is giving an ID. The column with the foreign key in the second table remains null.

For Instance: Insert into table t1 (t1_id,name, dpt) values (value1 (trigger with autoincrement for id), value2, value3); The same procedure is behind table 2, table 3 ... All constraints are written correctly

## Table 1 (Emp)

```
ID  Name  Department
1   Joe   HR
```

## Table 2 (Projects)

```
ID  Project EmpID
1   new     (null) -> must be 1
```

Thank you in advanced.

Constraint: `ALTER TABLE  "PROJECTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMP_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("EMP_ID")
      REFERENCES  "EMP" ("EMP_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE`

Trigger:   `create or replace TRIGGER Projects_TRG BEFORE 
  INSERT ON Projects FOR EACH ROW BEGIN :NEW.Project_ID := Projects_SEQ.NEXTVAL; 
END;`

How do i manage to populate the parent id from the parent table into the child table?

Please note that I used different names in my application.

Comment: APEX doesn't do table constraints; that's the job of the database.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you've misunderstood the purpose of a foreign key constraint. A foreign key constraint does NOT automatically propagate constraint values from the parent table to the child table. The purpose of the constraint is to ensure that the values of the key column in the child table, when populated, have matching values in the key column of the parent table. Your application is responsible for ensuring that the key column on the child table is populated with the appropriate value. The constraint doesn't do that for you. It's also perfectly legitimate to have a NULL in the key column of the child table, assuming the the column on the child table doesn't have a NOT NULL constraint on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do i manage to populate the value from the parent into the child table on my insert?

Comment: Well, you need to have some way of knowing which employees should be assigned to a project. I have no idea how you should do that in the context of whatever it is you're developing. I will suggest that you probably shouldn't have an employee ID on your PROJECT table, nor should you have a project ID on your EMP table. Instead, you should have a PROJECT_EMPLOYEE table which has a project ID and an employee ID - in this way it's simple to add multiple employees to a project, and one employee can be involved in multiple projects.